# How can I find a new god?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

After the initial character creation, is there any way to change the deity you're worshipping?

A certain bonus might have looked attractive on the startup screen but might not be working out (ie perhaps I chose to be atheist and realize 1% exp bonus is not that great).

Comment: Upvoted for a great title.

Comment: Upvoted for being a valid question.. All I have seen so far are those shrines you can pray at but they are not a permanent shift... seems odd with all the other things you can reset about your character that this part was left out so far.

Comment: @James Yes, I thought it was odd that there doesn't appear to be anywhere to change it, as new players it's tough to guess what might be needed later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is no way to change your patron God.

Source: I found the same question you asked on [the official forum of the game](http://forums.reckoning.amalur.com/showthread.php?4662-Changing-Patron-Gods) and all replies to this question were negative.

I wouldn't worry about it thought because patron god bufffs don't really make much of a difference,while i do agree that 1% experience buff is almost un-noticable other god buffs aren't really that great either.Some of the better god buffs are those 5% additional mana/HP and if you do some calculations you will see that those 5% really make almost no difference

Comment: It's really not hard to get 17/20% buffs to HP and mana as well. (Source: my lv29 mage has 600HP added from armour alone)

Comment: If you can provide a link to the official forum I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: @Stephen Here is the link of the question on official forum http://forums.reckoning.amalur.com/showthread.php?4662-Changing-Patron-Gods and here is link for the question on gamefaqs http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/991144-kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/61948895